# How can I run two sql queries in parallel using PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to start two sql queries so that they run concurrently?

In a php file, I am performing two queries on a `Postgresql` database. Using the values returned from the first two queries, I then perform a third query.

```
function one(){ 
   $query = pg_query($con, $sql);                               
   $a = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0);  
   return $a;
}
function two(){        
   $query = pg_query($con, $sql);                            
   $b = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0);  
   return $b;
}

function three($a, $b){ 
   //$a + $b used to construct query $sql
   $query = pg_query($con, $sql);                               
   $c = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0); 
   return $c;
}
```

Is it possible to run functions `one` and `two` at the same time? One other approach that I considered was to make `a` and `b` global variables and to initially set them to `null`. Then, instead of functions `one` and `two` returning any values, they just set the values of `a` and `b` when they are complete. I then constantly check to see if `a` and `b` are not null, and when this is true, call function `three`.

Searching on this topic I read about `pcntl` but I'm unclear if this is the best way of performing a calculation of this type.`pcntl` is not installed on my webhosting service (WebFaction), by default.

Another approach might be to use [pg_send_query_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-send-query-params.php) which enables me to perform the same query using different parameters which is probably quicker than my original approach.

Comment: Maybe you should look into Gearman for linux or PHP's mysqli_multi_query

Comment: A database has *never* two queries at the same time. You might want to look into transactions instead. Apart from that, PHP itself can only execute one line of code at the same time, too, so you can not execute two functions exactly in parallel with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run two queries concurrently using `Threads`.

But I will recommend to don't use `Thread` if you don't know how to handle them properly because it can cause `RACE` condition.

My advice will be to use directly call two functions and store them in variables and pass it to third function . It will not affect your page performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you create two different connections you can use asynchronous queries.

See pg_send_query(), pg_get_result() and pg_cancel_query() in the PHP manual for more information.

Note that each backend is single threaded so you must have one connection per query.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are more than likely the answer ...

https://www.php.net/Thread

Answer (score 0):

make a **query1** and **query2** in a function, store the result of the query1 and query2 in separate variable and pass those variables to function where the third query is in and perform the necessary action

```
function one()
{
  $query1="Your query here";
  $query2="Your second query here";
  $result=array_mergre($query1,$query2);
  return $result;
 }
```

Pass the $result to second function

```
 function two($result)
  {

    //Your actio ngoes here;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just updated my function description to make it clearer. I'm not sure - will this approach be quicker than what I already do?

Comment: How is it quicker than my current process?

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite sure if this can be performed by purely using PHP.

I will use javascript to have such an effect.
Suppose that I have a.php and b.php. I'll make an html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({url:'a.php'});
   $.ajax({url:'b.php'});
</script>
```

This one is actually not multithreading. It is like 2 people open 2 different web-page in almost the same time.

Comment: I considered using Javascript, but I thought the time overhead of transmitting data back and forth from server to webpage might not be worth it. I will test it out though, just to confirm.